# SwiftUI: Photo replacement when uploading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to implement it so that when the data has not loaded yet, there is one photo, and as soon as the photo has loaded, it is displayed. My data is loaded from Firebase and located in `cellViewModel`

```
if self.cellViewModel.card.photo.isEmpty{
                    
      Image("logoMain")
         .resizable()
         .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
   } else{
                    
       AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: cellViewModel.card.photo)!)
         .resizable()
         .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
         .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("Gray"), lineWidth: 0.5))
}
```

Comment: hello, you could use SwiftUI `AsyncImage` with a `placeholder`, is it what you want to achieve ?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use swiftui-cached-async-image. The image is displayed asynchronously and in addition it is cached

https://github.com/lorenzofiamingo/swiftui-cached-async-image

Exemple :

```
CachedAsyncImage(url: URL(string: "urlImageToDisplay "), transaction:         Transaction(animation: .spring()) ) { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .empty:
                    
                    Image("placeholder")

                    
                case .success(let image):
                    image

                    
                case .failure(_):
                    Image("placeholder")

                    
                @unknown default:
                    Image("placeholder")


                }
            }
```